# Unity UI children

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, dynamic, reference

I have recently started to create UI elements for a project using Unity.
The UI element has a image as a 'holder' and then, it has as childrens a text and a button.
When I am instantiating the UI element, I am unable to set the text to a specific value.

My question is: how can I have control over the text; how can I reference the text for each UI element that I instantiate, as to be able to change the name of the text when is instantiated,
and,
as well to be able to change the text when I am clicking the specific button of the UI element.

P.S. I am aware that for the button I need to have an event: "onclick. Add Listener"
Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create according component which holds references to the according items:

```c#
public class MyUIElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag in according objects of the prefab into the slots in the Inspector
    [Header("Own components")]
    [SerializeField] private Image _image;

    [Header("Children")]
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;
    [SerializeField] private Button _button;

    // As fallback get them on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_image) _image = GetComponent<Image>();
        if(!_text) _text = GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
        if(!_button) _button = GetComponentInChildren<Button>(true);
    }

    // Then either provide a direct access via Read-only property
    public Button Button => _button;

    // Or provide a method to call and handle the reference only internal
    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        _text.text = text;
    }
}
```

So when you instantiate the prefab like

```c#
[SerializeField] private MyUIElement prefab;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform someParentInACanvas;

...

var instance = Instantiate (prefab, someParentInACanvas);
instance.SetText("Hello...");
instance.Button.onClick.AddListener(() => { instance.SetText("World!"));
```